# JQuery select2 integration with Frontaccounting

Tags: jquery-select2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993771/how-to-integrate-jquery-select2-with-frontaccounting/33994148#

Hi  this is my first post. Here actually there is a similar post. I commented there.  But few told me to go with separate question. So my question is a duplicate of the above link.  I have not get a solution for this problem. Any solution for this one?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for it. Just bring the jquery select to files to your frontaccounting and include it on `header.inc` than you have to do one more step into it. Goto `Root_of_FA/company/0/js_cache/utilis.js`  and found the below line

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);if(!newwin){setFocus();}
}

}, false
```

around this will be line number : 27-36.  than change it like the below one.

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);if(!newwin){setFocus();}
}
 $(".combo").select2({
                  placeholder: "Select a state",
                  allowClear: true
            });
},false
```

that's it. It will work for you. If you need more details, check Here. 
[KV codes Select2 and Frontaccounting](http://www.kvcodes.com/2015/11/how-to-use-jquery-select-2-in-dropdown/)

Comment: Thank you Akelya. But there is some css issues in it.